# Creating Multi-hierarchy pivot table in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pivot-table

#### 1. Background

The .xls files I have now contain some parameters of multi-pollutant in many aspects for different sites.

I created an simplified dataframe below as an illustration:

[image]

Some declaration:

1. Column **Site** contain the  monitoring sites properties. In this case, Sites **S1**, **S2** are the only two locatio here.
2. Column **Time** contain the monitoring period for different sites.
3. **Species** A & B represents two chemical pollutants had been detected.
4. **Conc** is one key parameter for each species(A & B) represents the concentration. Notice that, the concentration of Species A should be measured twice as parallel.
5. **P** and **Q** are two different analysis experiments. Since species **A** has two samples, it has **P1**, **P2**, **P3** & **Q1**, **Q2** as the analysis results respectively. Species **B** has only be analyzed by **P**. So, **P1**, **P2**, **P3** are the only parameters.

After read some post on manipulating the **pivot_table** using **Pandas**, I want to have a try.

#### 2. My target

I presented my target file construction manually in Excel showing like this:

[image]

#### 3. My work

```
df = pd.ExcelFile("./test_file.xls")
df = df.parse("Sheet1")
pd.pivot_table(df,index = ["Site","Time","Species"])
```

This is the result:

[image]

#### Update

What I'm trying to figure out is to creat two columns **P** & **Q** and sub_columns below them.

I have re-upload my test file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQZW95Z1hhM2hvUTA/view?usp=sharing). Anyone interested in can download it.

- The **P** and **Q** tests are for each sample of species A respectively.
- The **Conc** test are for them both.

Any advice would be appreciate!

Comment: Sorry, I'll change my file. I have wrong about setting the _P_ and __Q__ tests. I have re-upload it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQZW95Z1hhM2hvUTA/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

You want the same dataframe, but with a better column index.

To create the first level:

```
level0 = df.columns.str.extract(r'([^\d]*)', expand=False)
```

then assign a multiindex to the columns attribute.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([level0, df.columns])
```

Looks like:

```
print df

                       Conc     P                 Q      
                       Conc    P1    P2    P3    Q1    Q2
Site Time     Species                                    
S1   20141222 A        0.79  0.02  0.62  1.05  0.01  1.73
     20141228 A        0.13  0.01  0.79  0.44  0.01  1.72
     20150103 B        0.48  0.03  1.39  0.84   NaN   NaN
     20150104 A        0.36  0.02  1.13  0.31  0.01  0.94
     20150109 A        0.14  0.01  0.64  0.35  0.00  1.00
     20150114 B        0.47  0.08  1.16  1.40   NaN   NaN
     20150115 A        0.62  0.02  0.90  0.95  0.01  2.63
     20150116 A        0.71  0.03  1.72  1.71  0.01  2.53
     20150121 B        0.61  0.03  0.67  0.87   NaN   NaN
S2   20141222 A        0.23  0.01  0.66  0.44  0.01  1.49
     20141228 A        0.42  0.06  0.99  1.56  0.00  2.18
     20150103 B        0.09  0.01  0.56  0.12   NaN   NaN
     20150104 A        0.18  0.01  0.56  0.36  0.00  0.67
     20150109 A        0.50  0.03  0.74  0.71  0.00  1.11
     20150114 B        0.64  0.06  1.76  0.92   NaN   NaN
     20150115 A        0.58  0.05  0.77  0.95  0.01  1.54
     20150116 A        0.93  0.04  1.33  0.69  0.00  0.82
     20150121 B        0.33  0.09  1.33  0.76   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can the __Conc__ column in your result  decompose into two sub coulmns?

Comment: It's not clear to me how you want to split it.  What is the rule that would determine what goes in Conc1 and Conc2.

Comment: Specie A has two samples , one goes to `Conc1`, the other goes to `Conc2`.

Comment: The only thing that signifies that there are 2 samples of A is that there are 2 rows of A together?  If this dataset were to get reordered, that information is lost.  What would be better is if there were a field identifying that it was sample 1 or sample 2.  In order to break out conc1 and conc2, I need to assign a sample id my self based on the oredering of samples of A.  I could do this, but not now.  If this hasn't been answered by the time I get to it, I'll figure something out for you.  If I were you, I'd record which sample it is in the data set.

Comment: I have tried your method after I upgrade my pandas to 0.18. And it works well. Sorry to bother you for one more question. How to locate the data for specific `site`  & `Time` & `Species` & `Data properties`(Conc, P, Q)?

Comment: For example, I have tried `df.query("Site == 'S1'")("Time == 20141222")("Species ="A"").P`. But it doesn't work!

Comment: What's more: To extend your subroutine in more situation. Set `P` as `Ion`, and __P1__, __P2__, etc will replaced by __Ion-Ca2+__, __Ion-Mg2+__ etc. How to get the `level0` using `df.column.str.extract()`?